# How do I properly display properties of deeply nested relationships in templates when using Ember Data and JSON API's include feature?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've been attempting to take advantage of the `{ include: 'level1,level1.level2,level1.level2.level3' }` option with Ember Data's find and query methods to load data in my route's model hooks. but as I understand it the route only pauses on the first level of data's Promise and all hasMany and belongsTo relationships have a chance to reach template code unfulfilled, and the template won't update once properties of those relationships do fulfilled.

I have a router like:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('user', { path: '/:user_id' });
  });
});
```

a User route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('user', params.user_id, { include: 'gifts,gifts.given_by,gifts.occasion.arranged_by' });
  }
});
```

a User model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  gifts: DS.hasMany('gift', { inverse: 'givenTo' })
});
```

a Gift model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  givenBy: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  givenTo: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  occasion: DS.belongsTo('occasion')
});
```

an Occasion model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  location: DS.belongsTo('location'),
  giftsGiven: DS.hasMany('gift')
});
```

a Location model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  occasions: DS.hasMany('occasion')
});
```

So for example, I have many levels of relationships I'm loading and wanting to use in my User template as part of the User's profile. In my User template I want to list in a table the Gifts the user has been given and related information like.

```
<h1>{{model.name}}'s Gifts{{/h1}}
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Gift Name</th>
    <th>Given By</th>
    <th>Occasion</th>
    <th>Where</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {{#each model.gifts as |gift|}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{gift.name}}</td>
      <td>{{gift.givenBy.name}}</td>
      <td>{{gift.occasion.name}}</td>
      <td>{{gift.occasion.location.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Let's say 10 gifts were returned from the database so the table is 10 rows long. What I'd expect to see is a fully populated table, what I see instead, consistent between page refreshes is the following:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ Gift Name ║ Given By ║ Occasion ║  Where   ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ Present 1 ║ Friend 1 ║ Birthday ║ The Park ║
║ Present 1 ║ Friend 1 ║ Birthday ║ The Park ║
║ Present 1 ║ Friend 1 ║ Birthday ║ The Park ║
║ Present 1 ║ Friend 1 ║ Birthday ║ The Park ║
║           ║ Friend 1 ║          ║ The Park ║
║           ║ Friend 1 ║ Birthday ║          ║
║           ║ Friend 1 ║ Birthday ║          ║
║           ║ Friend 1 ║ Birthday ║ The Park ║
║ Present 1 ║ Friend 1 ║          ║ The Park ║
║ Present 1 ║ Friend 1 ║ Birthday ║ The Park ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

I use the same data repeatedly on purpose to illustrate what I'm seeing. Even if a model's property renders correctly in some table cells, it won't in others, and seems to randomly but 100% consistently between page refreshes populate and not populate the same table cells. Which cells are populated and not are also different between User models in this example.

Hopefully this example makes sense, I know I could flatten data but in my actual app I can't and being able to include deeply nested relationships like this and have them show in templates correctly would be great.

It seems to mostly work, but fail for some reason that I imagine have to do with Promises. If I look in Ember inspector, all of the data is there, as evident by showing in most of the cells anyway.

What am I doing wrong and what can I do better if I want to take advantage of the `{ include: '' }` feature of Ember Data's JSON API adapter?

Comment: Do be aware that if you use Ember Inspector to inspect a relationship, it will actually load that data if it wasn't loaded yet (i.e. make the network call if necessary). So it may not be a good way of determining whether the store loaded a related record eagerly or lazily.

Comment: Can you confirm that the backend is returning all of the data every time? I am also unclear on whether the same user records consistently have the issue or if the rows change seemingly randomly. It would help if you could narrow the issue down a little.

Comment: @AlexMA Yes the data returns. The properties of the records appears correctly in most table cells, but fails in others. It's the same data, but 10 different ember objects created from the data as I understand it? And not all are created by the time the template renders is my guess.

Comment: @AlexMA Also I receive the same results with the Inspector closed, and I've deployed to a production environment and see the same behavior.

Comment: But is the same gift name blank every time or is it random?

Comment: @AlexMA It's random. It's exactly as I demo'd, table cell for table cell from my app, 6 out of 10 times it appears, 4 times not. Randomly different for other relationships, but consistently wrong between page refreshes. It's the same behavior in computed properties, if I do a Ember.computed('model.gifts', function() { this.get('model.gifts').forEach(gift => { debugger; }) }) I'll similarly see that there's 6 out of 10 gifts loaded, 4 undefined. By the time it reaches Ember inspector though they're all there. It's just leading up to the template render and everything before it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying everything in the comments. It's possible it's an Ember bug, but if there is some asynchronous stuff or other complexity in your view code that you've left out for simplicity, it's possible there is a race condition somewhere or an issue with how you're using the run loop. That being said, an ember-data guru might know better (ember's slack (specifically ember-data channel) might be a good place to go for more help).